# Store stream in a variable for later use

Tags: c++, c++11, stream, std, cout

In my code I have a place, where I have to pass the exact same `operator<<` stream to 2 different places. Once to an `ofstream` and once to `cout`:

```
m_logFileStream << "[" << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" << now->tm_sec << "]"
                << "[" << logLevelsStrings[(int)logline.logLevel] << "] "
                << logline.logString << endl;

        if(m_verbose)
        {
            cout << "[" << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" << now->tm_sec << "]"
                            << "[" << logLevelsStrings[(int)logline.logLevel] << "] "
                            << logline.logString << endl;
        }
```

`m_logFileStream` is an `ofstream`. If I would like to change the pattern I need to do it in two places. It would be more convenient top store it in a variable like this:

```
stringstream ss;
        ss      << "[" << now->tm_hour << ":" << now->tm_min << ":" << now->tm_sec << "]"
                << "[" << logLevelsStrings[(int)logline.logLevel] << "] "
                << logline.logString << endl;

        m_logFileStream << ss;

        if(m_verbose)
        {
            cout << ss;
        }
```

But for some reason instead of a proper output I am getting random hex numbers. What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit

`cout << ss.str();` works but `m_logFileStream << ss.str();` doesn't save anything to the file `m_logFileStream` is created for.

Comment: You're doing `m_logFileStream << ss;` which writes the address of the string stream.

Comment: @aslg but `ss.str()` and `ss.rdbuf()` doesnt work for me either. I am getting an empty file.

Comment: Did you `.close()` your file?

Comment: You are right, I havent. But does that mean that the file will be written at the moment I close it and I am not able to read it meanwhile its open?

Comment: Closing your file guarantees that your attempts to write to the file are completed. Are you trying to read from and write to the same file?

Comment: No, its not like that. I am writing to a log file in an application that is running on an embedded system, that most likely never closes properly, because it is started at the system boot up and never stopped. If it crashes without closing I wont get the log. Also sometimes I open the file while the logging is running, so I gues yes i am writing and reading in the same time, but in other processes.

Comment: I got the solution now. Instead of adding `endl` to the `stringstream` I have to add it manually here `m_logFileStream << ss.rdbuf() << endl;`. I felt like it is getting lost at some point there but I dont fully understand why and I know it plays a good role for the `ofstream`.

Comment: You should use `ss.str()` rather than `ss.rdbuf()`. The former is used to access the string representation of your input, and the latter is used to access the internal buffer which doesn't make sense for a stringstream (it doesn't have an external object to write to).

Comment: Ok, but then i will have to add endl enyways. Also it does work at the moment, so doest the ofstream make a conversion?

Comment: `std::endl` is more than just a fancy `'\n'`, it also flushes the stream.

Comment: If you don't want a newline, you can use << std::flush;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediately problem with the code was already discussed: inserting a stream results in the conversion operator to `void const*` being triggered and causing a pointer value (most likely the address of the stream) to be printed. The fix is to either use `ss.str()` or `ss.rdbuf()` instead, possibly followed by a `std::flush`. Note that `ss.str()` creates a `std::string` each time it is called. If the stream holds a lot of data that may not be too desirable. When inserting into a stream `ss.rdbuf()` should work as well and it can bypass creation of an extra stream. However, between using it twice the inserted stream would need to be set up to iterate over the sequence again, e.g., by seeking to the start.

So far for patching up the original design. I would recommend a different design to the overall problem, though: instead of creating a string first which is then inserted twice into two different streams, I'd create a stream which internally forwards to one or more streams internally. The magic enabling creating of a new stream is called a stream buffer, i.e., a class derived from `std::streambuf`.

A simple implementation of a stream buffer could look like this:

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

class teebuf
    : public std::streambuf
{
    char                         buffer[1024];
    std::vector<std::streambuf*> sbufs;

    int overflow(int c) {
        typedef std::streambuf::traits_type traits;
        if (!traits::eq_int_type(traits::eof(), c)) {
            *this->pptr() = traits::to_char_type(c);
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->sync() == 0? traits::not_eof(c): traits::eof();
    }
    int sync() {
        bool rc(false);
        if (this->pbase() != this->pptr()) {
            std::for_each(sbufs.begin(), sbufs.end(),
                [&](std::streambuf* sb){
                    sb->sputn(this->pbase(), this->pptr() - this->pbase());
                    sb->pubsync() != -1 || (rc = false);
                });
            this->setp(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1);
        }
        return rc? -1: 0;
    }
public:
    teebuf() { this->setp(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1); }
    void add(std::ostream& out){ sbufs.push_back(out.rdbuf()); }
    void remove(std::ostream& out){
        sbufs.erase(std::remove(sbufs.begin(), sbufs.end(), out.rdbuf()),
                    sbufs.end());
    }
};
```

Aside from somewhat trivial management of the list of stream buffers to forward the output to, this class overrides two `virtual` functions:

1. `overflow()` is called when the stream buffer's buffer (set up with `setp()`) is full but another character is being put into the buffer. All this function does is use the extra character saved for this case (if the function isn't called with the special value `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`) and call `sync()` (see below).
2. `sync()` is called when the current buffer needs to be flushed, e.g., because the user asked for the stream to be flushed using `std::flush` or because the buffer is full.

To actually use this stream buffer, you'd create an `std::ostream` and initialize it with a pointer to this `std::streambuf`. That's similar to what `std::ofstream` does with its `std::filebuf`. To make creation of a suitable stream a bit easier it makes sense to package this up:

```
class oteestream
    : private virtual teebuf
    , public std::ostream {
public:
    oteestream()
        : teebuf()
        , std::ostream(this) {
        this->init(this);
    }
    using teebuf::add;
    using teebuf::remove;
};
```

Assuming this stream buffer and custom stream are declared in the header `"teestream.h"` its use becomes rather straight forward:

```
#include "teestream.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream fout("tee.txt");
    oteestream    tee;
    tee.add(fout);
    tee.add(std::cout);
    tee << "hello, world!\n" << std::flush;
    tee.remove(std::cout);
    tee << "goodbye, world!\n" << std::flush;
}
```

The distinct advantage of packaging the sending to multiple streams into a class is that you don't even need to deal with forwarding the string in multiple places: you'd just write to the stream and flush (I'm somewhat [against the use of `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) to trigger flushing).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! I have to say that your coding style is driving me bonkeers and its hard for me to read, but thats probably because im not worthy. I think I understand the overall problem you have presented, but I have 2 followup questions: 1. Does it mean that using `sdbuf()` instead of `str()` solves the problem of additional `string` creation? Because the code still runs correctly. Also, I have read your blog post about `std::endl`, but the thing is that I kind of need the flush here as it seems to trigger the text to be saved into the file. Or should I use flush + `\n`?

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło: assuming you seek to the start of the stream before copying the content, using `rdbuf()` should avoid creating a temporary `std::string`. With respect to `std::endl` the problem is that you can't tell whether the flush is intentional or not when `std::endl` is used. Thus, I'd output a newline character `'\n'` followed by an explicit `std::flush` instead of using `std::endl`.
With respect to my coding style: I just like to write correct code without stating anything unnecessary and using DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself; oddly, the reverse would have the same abbreviation...).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have applied your code and made it take a bit more space to analyze it better. Everything works.